# Display pattern count when highlighting searched pattern

Tags: search, highlight

Running Neovim 0.9, I have this mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>l :<c-u>let @/ = '\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'\|set hlsearch<CR>wb
```

which is a shortcut to highlight search the whole word under cursor. The problem is that it doesn't display the matched pattern count (the e.g. `[5/20]` count at the bottom right of the window). How can I trigger this mapping to also display the count? Or how can I implement a different mapping that highlights the current word under cursor without causing the screen to jump (e.g. not with `*` or `#`)

Answer (score 1):

[https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'shortmess'](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27shortmess%27)

`set shortmess-=S`

If 'S' is present you won't get this message, but I suggest using `:normal` instead of `let @/ =` to achieve what you want instead of setting the register, which I tested it will not trigger the message.

`:nnoremap <leader>l :set hlsearch<CR>/<C-R>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>`

Add the `^M`-character (CR, carriage return) by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will not work if you simply type ^M caret-m.

Also check out https://github.com/obcat/vim-hitspop I think its a good fit for a popup, since normally this message is [limited to 99 matches.](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/267bc57d21fd7cc995ea91028de912d92d5fd662/src/nvim/search.c#L4325-L4333)

Comment: Your use of `expand` in the middle of the `:normal /` doesn’t look quite right. FWIW I would write `nnoremap <leader>l *` or `nnoremap <leader>l /\<<C-r><C-w>\><Enter>`

Comment: Thanks for catching.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble the macros you provided cause the screen to jump if there are other occurrences of the word, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @reject-cookies tried to put this in place of setting `let @/` ?

Comment: @dza I tried this but it doesn't do anything `nnoremap <silent> <leader>l :<c-u>:normal /expand('<cword>')/^M:set hlsearch<CR>wb`

Comment: @reject-cookies I have seen mappings like `*N` before to stay in place.

Comment: @reject-cookies remove the `:` from normal and add back `|`-pipe before `set hlsearch` and remove `:` there too. I just left it there to make you test it from commandline. Maybe try simpler first then add on. `:` is only needed to start commandline.

Comment: Now it's just searching for the literal pattern `expand('<cword>')`. I'm not sure how to correct this. I'll try working on it again later

Comment: @reject-cookies try this `:nnoremap <leader>l /<C-R>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>:set hlsearch<CR>` I removed `<silent>` just for sake of testing, add wb if you like

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately, it doesn't display the count and it also jumps to the next occurrence of the term.

Comment: @reject-cookies  `:nnoremap <leader>l :set hlsearch<CR>/<C-R>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>` works, make sure you don't have `S` in `set showmess?` and `set showmatch` is set. Works I just tested on clean vim.

Comment: Unfortunately it jumps to the next result because it calls the `/` search functionality. So it is a bit similar to `*`.

Comment: @reject-cookies not sure what you mean.. is this why you added `wb` ? add it back.

Comment: No the `wb` is to go back to the beginning of the word (first character). The mapping you provided jumps to the next occurrence of the word, similar to `*`'s functionality. It does show the count though at least

Comment: @reject-cookies easy though.. just add `N` at the end like Ben suggested. `nnoremap <leader>l :set hlsearch<CR>/<C-R>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>N` I still don't get why you can't make it work..